# dplyr: difference in values between end year and start year

Tags: r, dplyr

Using this `data.frame`

```
siteID <- c(rep("site1", 16), rep("site2", 16), rep("site3", 16),rep("site4", 16))
YEAR <-   rep(c("2003", "2004", "2005", "2006"), 16)
parameter <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4))
value <- c(seq(1, 4, by=1), seq(10, 40, by=10), seq(12, 18, by=2), seq(5, 20, by=5),
           seq(3, 12, by=3), sample(13:18, 4), sample(15:22, 4), sample(10:18, 4),
           seq(7, 1, by=-2), sample(15:22, 4), sample(15:19, 4), sample(10:20, 4),
           seq(8, 5, by=-1), seq(50, 20, by=-10), seq(16, 10, by=-2), seq(20, 5, by=-5))
df <- data.frame(siteID, parameter, YEAR, value)

head(df, 20)
> head(df, 20)
   siteID parameter YEAR value
1   site1         A 2003     1
2   site1         A 2004     2
3   site1         A 2005     3
4   site1         A 2006     4
5   site1         B 2003    10
6   site1         B 2004    20
7   site1         B 2005    30
8   site1         B 2006    40
9   site1         C 2003    12
10  site1         C 2004    14
11  site1         C 2005    16
12  site1         C 2006    18
13  site1         D 2003     5
14  site1         D 2004    10
15  site1         D 2005    15
16  site1         D 2006    20
17  site2         A 2003     3
18  site2         A 2004     6
19  site2         A 2005     9
20  site2         A 2006    12
```

I want to get the difference in value for each parameter between the end year and start year.

The result will look like this

```
siteID parameter difference
site1         A      3
site1         B      30
site1         C      6
site1         D      15
```

If the data was converted from long format to wide format, this could be done by subtracting the start year column (2003) from end year column (2006).

However, I'd like to do it using `dplyr` and without converting the data to wide format.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We group by 'siteID', 'parameter', and get the difference between 'value' that corresponds to maximum 'YEAR' and minimum 'YEAR'.  The `which.max` and `which.min` returns the row index of the maximum/minimum values of 'YEAR'.

```
res <- df %>%
         group_by(siteID, parameter) %>%
         summarise(difference = value[which.max(YEAR)]-value[which.min(YEAR)])
head(res, 4)
#  siteID parameter difference
#  (fctr)    (fctr)      (dbl)
#1  site1         A          3
#2  site1         B         30
#3  site1         C          6
#4  site1         D         15
```